# Como usar as urls amigáveis em um sistema php?

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Estou trabalhando em um site, primeiro site que faço sem `Wordpress` e gostaria de vossa ajuda para implementar as urls amigáveis. Eu não tenho muito conhecimento em urls amigáveis e `.htaccess` mas estou tentando aprender. O meu `.htacces` inicial é esse:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Eu quero fazer um post e não quero retornar alguma coisa do tipo:

```
/artigos/eu-quero-aprender-como-funciona-htaccess
```

**Pergunta:** Tenho que fazer um script que já envia a url amigável para o banco?

**Pergunta 2**: Podem por favor me demonstrar como conseguir a url citada acima através do `.htaccess`? Seria uma base para eu continuar o [**sistema**](http://dent.axitech.com.br).

Desculpe se minha pergunta não tem tantos detalhes ou se pareço estar pedindo pra fazerem pra mim. Não se trata disso.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que já vi umas 3 perguntas dessas nesse site

Answer (score 2):

**Pergunta 1:** Tenho que fazer um script que já envia a URL amigável para o banco?

Não precisa, mas se não fizer isso você vai ter um esforço maior para buscar no seu banco de dados, indico já cadastrar o post no banco de dados com o caminho. O Wordpress faz isso.

**Pergunta 2:** Podem por favor me demonstrar como conseguir a url citada acima através do .htaccess? Seria uma base para eu continuar o sistema.

```
RewriteRule ^artigos/(.*) artigos.php?qualartigo=$1

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```